# I am having problems while updating captions using Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, put, caption, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use this service and I'm having some trouble. I'm passing my access token as a header, a file `.sbv` (which is the one I've modified and I want to exchange it with the one that is on Youtube) and a body containing the caption id I want to update. However, I'm getting the following response from Youtube api:

[image]

I'm sure that the caption id I'm passing as parameter isn't wrong beacause I'm getting it directly from the Caption list service given by Youtube api.

Any help would be helpful. It's been day I've been dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally could deal with the problem sending two different requests and making the request resumable (sending the PUT request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&uploadType=resumable). In the first request I sent the json part, and in the second one, the file. The second request was sent as a PUT request as well. However, it wasn't given to the same URL. I sent it to the header returned after the first request called "Location".